# Service cannot be started. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: windows-services

When trying to install my 32bit service on a Windows 64bit machine my installer places the files in SysWOW64 directory and when I attempt to start the service an event is written to the event log, the log shows:

"Service cannot be started. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'"

I have copied the files manually to the System32 directory but this makes no difference.

Any suggestions as to why my service won't start?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you install your service to the system folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the service fails to load the assembly System.ServiceModel on startup. 
Is either .NET Framework 3.0 or 3.5 installed on the machine?

Comment: .Net 3.5 wasn't installed! Thanks for that.

Comment: In my case it was that .net 4.5 wasn't installed only 4.0